# Не срабатывает нажатие радио кнопок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не срабатывает скрыть / показать текст при выборе кнопок

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery('form.checkout').on('change','input[name^='shipping_method']', function()  
{
var val = jQuery( this ).val();
if (val.match('^local_pickup'))  {[ 
jQuery('.address-field').fadeOut();
} else {
jQuery('.address-field').fadeIn();
}
));
</script>
```

```js
jQuery('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name^='shipping_method']', function() {
  var val = jQuery(this).val();
  if (val.match('^local_pickup')) {
    [
      jQuery('.address-field').fadeOut();
    } else {
      jQuery('.address-field').fadeIn();
    }
));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А Java тут при чём?

Answer (score 1):

1. Кавычки внутри кавычек.
2. Со скобками полный бардак.

```js
jQuery('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name^=\'shipping_method\']', function() {
  var val = jQuery(this).val();
  if (val.match('^local_pickup')) {
    jQuery('.address-field').fadeOut();
  } else {
    jQuery('.address-field').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="checkout">
  <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="local_pickup:6"/>
  <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="free_shipping:6"/>
  <div class="address-field">Address Field</div>
</form>
```

Comment: невозможно прикрепить скрин,  вот как это все выглядит в проге:  https://i.paste.pics/1bceca727b580f5ac246c509a9ed79eb.png

Comment: @РодинаМарина Кхм, кхм. А зачем Вы написали в вопросе этот ужас? Код в ответе работает.

Comment: @РодинаМарина Добавьте в вопрос Ваш html. Только скопируйте тот, который у Вас в действительности есть.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/p00c8y не выходит